# Django Serializer Validator not working with allow_blank and read_only arguments

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

i have a serializer which has

```
some_field = CharField(allow_null=False, allow_blank=False, read_only=True)
```

The problem is that i do not get any errors if i try to serialize Serializer(data={'some_field': '').is_valid(raise_exception=True) or Null.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Since it's a read-only field, it will not get deserialized into a python object. Read-only fields will only be included when you create a serializer with a model instance and access the `serializer.data` attribute. Hence, the validation for `some_field` passed in this case.

Comment: Does that mean i have to manually check if the some_field type that got send with the request is the correct one, or will django do that before it lands in the endpoint function?

Comment: What do you mean by manually checking that it is the correct one?